# iOS: Signing the build when compiling a new app

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an individual developer account. I'm working with another developer to build a brand new app on my account. The first feature is passwordless login via Firebase.

I've added him to the app as a developer on AppStore connect. But since it's not an organization, I'm unable to add him to developer.apple.com.

Is there a way, he can sign the build when compiling? Or is there something I need to do (as far as certificates)? Short of signing up for an organization account (which I will do eventually), what's do you advise him to do to get the app signed while compiling so the deep linking can be tested? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no practical way to do this using  Automatic Codesigning (except for you to give him your Apple credentials which is a bad idea).

You can manually generate a provisioning profile + certificate on Apple Developer and send them to him to sign the app manually